Failed to send buy transaction error: 0xbbf
I am trying to send Solana transactions but I am getting the following error Failed to send buy transaction: ReasonTransaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xbbf Result: Error:-32002 Result: Reason:Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xbbf (0xbbf = 3007). This appears to be caused by an account being owned by a different program but I am not sure what is the exact issue here.
I was able to send an ATA transaction just fine but then when I went to send the actual transaction it fails here is my C# code.
                double tokenPrice = token.VirtualSolReserves / token.VirtualTokenReserves;
                double tokensToBuy = solToSpend / tokenPrice;
                ulong tokenAmountLamports = (ulong)(tokensToBuy * TradeTokenData.TokenLamports);
                ulong maxSolLamports = (ulong)(solToSpend * TradeTokenData.SolLamports * slippage);

                byte[] buyData = new byte[24];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(BUY_DISCRIMINATOR), 0, buyData, 0, 8);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(tokenAmountLamports), 0, buyData, 8, 8);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(maxSolLamports), 0, buyData, 16, 8);

                Form1.DebugMessages.Add($"Buying Rn TokenPrice:{tokenPrice} TokensToBuy:{tokensToBuy} LamportAmount:{tokenAmountLamports} MaxSolLamparts:{maxSolLamports} " +
                    $"VirtualSol:{token.VirtualSolReserves} VirtualTokens:{token.VirtualTokenReserves}");

                TransactionInstruction buyInstruction = new TransactionInstruction 
                {
                    ProgramId = PUMP_PROGRAM_KEY.KeyBytes,
                    Keys = new List<AccountMeta>
                    {
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(PUMP_GLOBAL_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(PUMP_FEE_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(mintKey, false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(new PublicKey(token.BondingCurve), false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(new PublicKey(token.AssociatedBondingCurve), false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(associatedTokenAddress, false),
                    AccountMeta.Writable(_wallet.Account.PublicKey, true),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(SYSTEM_PROGRAM_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(SYSTEM_TOKEN_PROGRAM_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(SYSTEM_RENT_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(PUMP_EVENT_AUTHORITY_KEY, false),
                    AccountMeta.ReadOnly(PUMP_PROGRAM_KEY, false),
                    },
                    Data = buyData
                };

                Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                transaction.Add(buyInstruction);
                transaction.FeePayer = _wallet.Account.PublicKey;
                transaction.RecentBlockHash = recentBlockhash;

                transaction.Sign(_wallet.Account);
   
                var sendResponse = await rpcClient.SendTransactionAsync(transaction.Serialize(), skipPreflight: false); //, Commitment.Processed
                if (!sendResponse.WasSuccessful)
                {
                    Form1.DebugMessages.Add($"Failed to send buy transaction: Reason{sendResponse.Reason} Result:{sendResponse.Result} Error:{sendResponse.ServerErrorCode} Result:{sendResponse.Result} Reason:{sendResponse.Reason}");
                    throw new Exception($"Failed to send buy transaction: Reason{sendResponse.Reason}");
                }

Also when should one use Processed over Finalized when sending transactions what are the pros and cons of each when sending transactions.
